# Webpack require Dynamic Path

Tags: angular, webpack, require

Hello when I am trying to require path dynamically I was getting module not found error. But given same string is loading fine.

Working:

```
require('../' + 'components/profilebanner/profile.banner.component');
```

Not Working:

```
let path = '../components/profilebanner/profile.banner.component';
require(path);
```

I tried with context and tweaking in regex but I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Context:

```
require.context('.', true, /^((?![\\/]node_modules|components[\\/]).)*\.md$/)('../components/profilebanner/profile.banner.component');
```

Comment: Context which I took was correct. Silly mistake which I did unknowingly.

`code
let component = require.context('../../../src', true, /^((?![\\/]node_modules|typings|core|src[\\/]).)*\.ts$/)(path);`